# Hide POST origin with iframes?

Tags: ajax, http, post, iframe, referrer

I'm using a third party API (Azure PlayFab) that I'm making POST requests to. I would like to not give all my valuable analytics information to Microsoft though, and not share the origin of my users.

If I make the requests through an iframe, will that suitably change the origin of the request so that the frame parent can't be seen?

Comment: if by `origin` you mean the `ip address` users come from - it's not going to change much because iframe still runs on the same user's device. you could potentially scramble some http headers by doing so but it seems a bit fiddly. maybe you should consider proxying all API requests through your own backend instead?

Comment: @timur Hi I'm trying to hide my server's domain not my user's ip. I want my users to go directly to playfab without showing that it's coming from my domain. I need them to come from the users directly not all my server which wouldn't pass rate limits.

Comment: oh, okay. then you probably could have clients talk to the API from your main browser window, seems like you won't benefit from an extra iframe

Comment: You can create a proxy server and send all the post requests through it.

Comment: Even if you'll hide `origin` header, what you'll do with [host](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) header? That header shows your domain as well and you can't remove it.

Comment: @cassandrad It would be through a proxy server that shows a dummy domain as Aeyzaz Khan says. The idea is to run it through an iframe without showing the parent frame. I just wasn't sure if using an iframe would still reveal anything involving the parent frame.